# How to get a J. Appl. Phys. like bibliography with scrreprt document class?

Tags: bibliographies, koma-script, revtex

J. Appl. Phys. like bibliography can be generated by using revtex4-1 document class with jap option and aipnum4-1 bibliographystyle. But how can I get that J. Appl. Phys. like bibliography with scrreprt document class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APS classes make use of the `natbib` package, so this should work:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
  @ARTICLE{paper1,
    author = {{Gouzerh}, J. and {Stashkevich}, A.~A. and {Kovshikov}, N.~G. and 
      {Matyushev}, V.~V. and {Desvignes}, J.~M.},
    title = "{Reflection of magnetostatic waves from a laser-annealed grating in a garnet film}",
    journal = {Journal of Magnetism and Magnetic Materials},
    year = 1991,
    month = oct,
    volume = 101,
    pages = {189-190},
    doi = {10.1016/0304-8853(91)90723-N},
    adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1991JMMM..101..189G},
    adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
  }
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

Something to cite~\cite{paper1}.

\bibliography{refs}
\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}

\end{document}
```

The bibliography then looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Something is still missing. Using what you suggest produces Bibliography entries looking like this: [191] J. Gouzerh, A. A. Stashkevich, N. G. Kovshikov, V. V. Matyushev, and J. M.
Desvignes, “bibfield journal “bibinfo journal Journal of Magnetism and Magnetic
Materials“ “textbf “bibinfo volume 101,“ “bibinfo pages 189 (“bibinfo year 1991).

Comment: @user42569 Maybe you have other packages that interfere with the code. I've extended the sample code and added a figure with the output it produces for me.

Comment: It seems thing to be working now. The sad thing that I don't remember what I did to fix it.